# Is it possible to make a query like this?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table like this on mySQL db:

| Olimpiade | Sport | Disciplina | Categoria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| London 2012 | Athletics | 100m | men |
| London 2012 | Athletics | 100m | woman |
| Beijing 2008 | Athletics | 200m | men |
| Beijing 2008 | Athletics | 200m | women |
| Athens 2004 | Athletics | 800m | men |
| Athens 2004 | Athletics | 800m | women |

and so on.
I don't know if I could set up a query like this, but what I would like to get is a result as follow:

| Disciplina | Categoria | London 2012 | Beijing 2008 | Athens 2004 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100m | men | yes | no | yes |
| 100m | women | yes | yes | no |
| 200m | men | yes | no | yes |
| 200m | women | yes | yes | no |
| 800m | men | yes | yes | yes |
| 800m | women | yes | yes | yes |

that is if the trial is present or not for that olympics edition.

Comment: belongs to [pivot table](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78) problem.

Comment: Have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table). Then try yourself first.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, use CASE like this,

```
Select Disciplina, Categoria, 
CASE when Olimpiade = 'London 2012' then 'yes' else 'no' end as 'London 2012', 
CASE when Olimpiade = 'Beijing 2008' then 'yes' else 'no' end as 'Biejing 2008',
CASE when Olimpiade = 'Athens 2004' then 'yes' else 'no' end as 'Athens 2004'    from tableName group by Disciplina, Categoria order by Disciplina, Categoria
```

Comment: Ok, but it's strange because I get 'yes' only on first (London 2012) and the others 'no', even if I have to get 'yes'. It seems it works only for the first case

Answer (score 3):

You can build a query with an inner select. The inner select prepares data by adding the columns. The outer select groups the data:

```
SELECT
    Disciplina,
    Categoria,
    IF (MAX(`London 2012`) > 0, 'yes', 'no') AS 'London 2012',
    IF (MAX(`Beijing 2008`) > 0, 'yes', 'no') AS 'Beijing 2008',
    IF (MAX(`Athens 2004`) > 0, 'yes', 'no') AS 'Athens 2004'
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Disciplina, 
            Categoria, 
            IF (Olimpiade = 'London 2012', 1, 0) AS 'London 2012',
            IF (Olimpiade = 'Beijing 2008', 1, 0) AS 'Beijing 2008',
            IF (Olimpiade = 'Athens 2004', 1, 0) AS 'Athens 2004'
        FROM YourTableName
    ) AS Games
GROUP BY Disciplina, Categoria
ORDER BY Disciplina, Categoria
```

You have to replace `YourTableName` with the name of your table.